# I got this error trying to run my React app on a iOS and Android device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

this, what I do?:

> Unable to resolve module `.config/config.js` from `App.js`:
>
> None of these files exist:   *
>   ...........config\config.js(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
>   * ...........config\config.js\index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
>
> ABI37_0_0facebook::ABI37_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function const&, std::__1::function, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
>   ABI37_0_0facebook::ABI37_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function const&, std::__1::function, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
>   0C7A69CD-F2EE-3426-BFD8-742C903D3D07
>   0C7A69CD-F2EE-3426-BFD8-742C903D3D07
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   GSEventRunModal UIApplicationMain Exponent
>   9D122047-19B7-36A2-A892-27401F9E0E6C

Comment: first, make sure to read about how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: not a correct way to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not `importing` it in correct way:
instead of `.config` it should be `./config`